# Powershell Certificate Extensions export-csv

Tags: csv, powershell, x509certificate, export-to-csv

I'm trying to gather certificate extensions into a csv. The PowerShell commands seem to display just fine within PowerShell but when piped to a csv they display other types of data?

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine -Recurse
($cert.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "Key Usage"}).Format(1) | Export-Csv C:\Folder\File.csv
```

After searching the web I tried something different but still was unable to get the data to get captured and displayed as it does within PowerShell.

```
$cert=Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine -Recurse           
$sanExt=$cert.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -match "subject alternative name"}            
$sanObjs = new-object -ComObject X509Enrollment.CX509ExtensionAlternativeNames            
$altNamesStr=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($sanExt.RawData)            
$sanObjs.InitializeDecode(1, $altNamesStr)            
Foreach ($SAN in $sanObjs.AlternativeNames) {$SAN.strValue}
$sanExt.Format(1) | Export-Csv C:\Folder\File.csv
```

Comment: Certificate objects in powershell contain several nested objects and arrays. As such they are not well suited for simply piping to a CSV file. Exporting to JSON or XML where such structures are supported would be a better option if you want to retain all of the information. What properties exactly are you trying to export?

Comment: Thanks for your time TheMadTechnician, that's unfortunate for my situation. I'm trying to gather all of the X.509 extensions of each CA installed on the LocalMachine stores. I'm not familiar with exporting to JSON or XML though, do you have an example I could reference?

Comment: Exporting to JSON is pretty simple: `$cert | ConvertTo-JSON | Set-Content C:\Path\To\File.txt` I think a better question would be the reason for saving this all to file. Is it for human eyes, or will it be digested by a script/application at some point?

Comment: Thanks for the response TheMadTechnician. Yes the data is digested into  Splunk> for visualization. I'll give your code a run and see how it looks :)

On another note I did find this blog today which helped explain why the data in PowerShell is formatted differently than when it's piped into a csv. I'm newer to powershell so this helped me understand a bit more. http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/powershell-objects-and-output

Comment: TheMadTechnician, I was able to get the data into JSON format, sadly the data was still in integer format. However I did succeed in exporting to csv. After some time exploring and posting on other PowerShell focused community forums I got the solution to my problem. This allowed me to also format the data as I need into a csv to be later digested into Splunk> `$cert = Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine -Recurse
($cert.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "Key Usage"}).Format(1) |
Select-Object -Property @{Name="Certificate";Expression={$_}} |
Export-csv -Path C:\Folder\file.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others looking to also gather the extension fields, this was my resolution:

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine -Recurse
($cert.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "Key Usage"}).Format(1) |
Select-Object -Property @{Name="Certificate";Expression={$_}} |
Export-csv -Path C:\Folder\file.csv`
```